# Accepting submissions [Angularjs]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I truing to submit form with angularjs but not working anyone can find where is my mistake:

My form:

```
 <form ng-controller="ReviewsController as reviewCtrl" ng-submit="reviewCtrl.addReview(product)">
                <blockquote >
                    <b>Stars: {{ reviewCtrl.review.stars }}</b>
                    {{ reviewCtrl.review.body }}
                    <cite>by: {{reciewsCtrl.review.author}}</cite>
                </blockquote>  
                    <select ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.stars">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="reviewCtrl.review.body"/>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="reciewsCtrl.review.author"/>
                    <input type="submit"/>

                </form>
```

app.js

```
 //Reviews
    app.controller('ReviewsController' ,function(){
        this.review = {};

        this.addReview = function(product) {

            product.reviews.push(this.review);
        };
    });
```

This error I get into console:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at addReview (http://localhost/angular/js/app.js:107:25)
    at fn (eval at  (http://localhost/angular/js/angular.min.js:1:0), :4:353)
    at f (http://localhost/angular/js/angular.min.js:250:394)
    at m.$eval (http://localhost/angular/js/angular.min.js:134:83)
    at m.$apply (http://localhost/angular/js/angular.min.js:134:309)
    at HTMLFormElement. (http://localhost/angular/js/angular.min.js:250:446)
    at HTMLFormElement.m.event.dispatch (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js:3:8549)
    at HTMLFormElement.r.handle (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js:3:5259)

Comment: `product` is a string. it has no `reviews` property.

Comment: what `product` should be?

Comment: i dont know - its your app. it should be something that has `reviews` property that the value has a `push` function.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a literal string ('gems') to the addReview method and it looks to me from your code like that method is expecting a "product" object with an array property called "reviews".

Comment: I need to add new product into `gems` array `var gems = 
  [{
      reviews: [
          {
              stars: 5,
              body: "Great product",
              author: "zamora@hotmail.rs"
          },
          {
              stars: 3,
              body: "Bot bad",
              author: "v@hotmail.rs"
          }
      ]
  },
  {`....